# Write an 'r' and a 'd' of a specific type

Tags: typography

In the equations, I'd like to use an 'r' and a 'd' as follows:

[image]

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: I am deeply cofused. should the letters look like this? If so, you have to find *the font* that shows the letters the way you want. On the other hand, he first letter looks like a gamma.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `calligra` font (see http://www.ctan.org/pkg/calligra and http://www.ctan.org/pkg/calligra-type1).

A potential alternative is the use of Zapf Chancery (a widely available font, use the package `chancery` from the psnffss bundle: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/psnfss) that is probably cursive enough for you purposes.